# Comparing values in two different arrays for equality

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to compare two different arrays for equality between all values, except the one in the same position in the other array:
for example array1[0]==array2[1] but not array1[0]==array2[0]
I'm having a little bit of trouble and know there must be an easier way than what I'm doing which is this: 
This is in c by the way

```
for(int r=1; r<4;4++){
    if(choicearray[r]==comparray[r+1]||choicearray[r]==comparray[r-1] || choicearray[r]==comparray[r+2]|| choicearray[r]==comparray[r-2] || choicearray[r]==comparray[r-3] || choicearray[r]==comparray[r+3]){
    printf("w "); 
         e++;
   }
  }
```

Both arrays contain 4 characters

Comment: Your code won't work: `4++`?

Comment: can you provide 2 examples: where 2 arrays are the same and where 2 arrays are different according to logic described?

Comment: Please post compilable code.

Answer (score 3):

First of all remember that array are indexed starting from 0 (in your case 0 to 3).

You have to loop throught the first array then loop through the second array.

```
int n=4;
for(int r=0; r<n; r++){
    for(int q=0; q<n; q++){
        if(arrayA[r]==arrayB[q] && q!=r)
             printf("w ");
    }
}
```

The condition `q!=r` check that only different indexes are compared.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you can try to use two loops, each to control iteration of one array like so:

```
for (int r=0; r<4;r++){
    for (int s=0; s<4;s++){
        if (s!=r){
            //do your comparing
        }
    } 
}
```